# Transaction in orientdb and waterline

Tags: sails.js, orientdb, waterline, sails-orientdb

I am trying to to create transaction in waterline but I am getting this error from OrientDB:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.BEGIN
```

Here is my code:

```
 try {
  itemsModel.query("BEGIN", function(err) { if (err) {throw new Error(err);}
    itemsModel.update({id:items_ids,status:ACTIVE},{status:INACTIVE})
      .exec(function(err, INA_items){ if (err) {throw new Error(err);}
        if (INA_items.length != items_ids.length ) {throw new Error({err:RECORD_NOT_FOUND});}
        itemsModel.query("COMMIT", function(err) { if (err) {throw new Error({err:MSG.RECORD_NOT_FOUND,title:"ITEMS"});} });
      });
  });
}
catch(e){
  itemsModel.query("ROLLBACK", function(err) { 
    if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
    return res.serverError(e);  
  });
}
```

I also checked `BEGIN` command directly in orientdb, but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question as it stands is mixing several different concepts, I'll try to address one by one:

1. Waterline's API itself does not support transactions (check [issue #755](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/755));
2. It looks like you are using `sails-orientdb` adapter and from it you are executing a *raw* SQL query;
3. The SQL query you are executing in the second line of your example is just `BEGIN` and that's where OrientDB itself is throwing an error. A transaction SQL query must be something like:

   ```
   begin
   let account = create vertex Account set name = 'Luke'
   let city = select from City where name = 'London'
   let edge = create edge Lives from $account to $city
   commit retry 100
   return $edge
   ```

   Example taken from [OrientDB docs](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/SQL-batch.html#optimistic-transaction).
4. Alternatively you can use transactions in a more *javascript style* by making use of the [Oriento](https://github.com/codemix/oriento) DB object. Assuming you are using `sails-orientdb` you can get the Oriento DB object like this:

   ```
   var db = itemsModel.getDB();

   // using oriento syntax, you can do something like
   var tx = db.begin();
   tx.create({
     '@class': 'TestClass',
     name: 'item3'
   });
   return tx.commit()
   .then(function (results) {
     console.log(results.created.length);  // should be 1
   });
   ```

   Example taken from [Oriento tests](https://github.com/codemix/oriento/blob/master/test/db/transaction-test.js#L41). Another good example can be found at [Oriento's example folder](https://github.com/codemix/oriento/blob/master/example/transactions.js).

Comment: Sorry. I am using waterline-orientdb.

Comment: Hey @Dário I am trying to follow 4 option above. but i am getting this execption `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on this line `var db = itemsModel.getDB();`

Comment: Hey @9me, are you using the latest version of `waterline-orientdb`? Also, is `itemsModel` a model as those returned by `waterline.initialize()`? You can check a working example of `.getDB()` on this link: https://github.com/appscot/waterline-orientdb/blob/master/test/integration-orientdb/tests/adapterCustomMethods/getDB_Server.js#L6

Comment: Hi @Dário i am using global.WL_MODELS = all models in app.js ( main file) and i want to get DB object like WL_MODELS.users.getDB() but I got this error `TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at module.exports.DbHelper.getDB (node_modules\waterline-orientdb\lib\connection.js:412:12)
    at module.exports.adapter.getDB (node_modules\waterline-orientdb\lib\adapter.js:343:38)
    at self.(anonymous function) [as getDB] (node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\adapters.js:35:29)` What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Which version of sails-orientdb (it's no longer called waterline-orientdb) are you using? Regarding the error, `waterline-orientdb\lib\connection.js:412:12` is in `createEdge()` method ([connection.js:412](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L412)). Either you are not using the latest version or your error is happening somewhere else.

Comment: I am using version `0.10.42`

Comment: That's recent enough, if you look at connection.js code around [line 412](https://github.com/appscot/sails-orientdb/blob/v0.10.42/lib/connection.js#L412) you'll see the error you mentioned is coming from `.createEdge()`, so your problem doesn't seem to be related to `.query()` but somewhere else...