# How to rollback with sails-orientdb?

Tags: transactions, rollback, orientdb, waterline, sails-orientdb

I am a newbie at sails-orientdb. I want to implement transaction via sails-orientdb. But currently, I don't know how to rollback my query when it's get some errors.

I've read this article before, [Transaction in orientdb and waterline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29236354/transaction-in-orientdb-and-waterline/29238714#29238714). But it's not help for my case.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: var db = app.models.user.getDB();
var tx = db.begin();
tx.create(req.body);

return tx.commit().then(function (results) {
  res.json(results.created);
});

Comment: Sorry for my code is too ugly. I want to know my query is error or not, if it got error I want to rollback all thing I have done. But the function .rollback() is undefined.

Comment: @jezrael, here is my expected, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586175/waterline-transaction-through-sails-orientdb, but .rollback() function is not defined.

Comment: Tam Pham, sails-orientb (and waterline) does not support transactions, hence it does not support `.rollback`. OrientDB transactions are supported via Oriento (which you can access via `.getDB()`) so you need to find out how to do a rollback in Oriento.